# ASP.net create an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, gdi+

Lost on this one, I've developed a drag and drop area.

I have:

A set of images with x,y width and height all known
A set of text labels, all with x,y,fontsize,text etc all known

How can I  convert this into an image file so I can thumbnail it?  Don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bitmap of the size you need, grab a graphics instance from it, and begin drawing.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(height,width);
using gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) {
  // then draw on the gfx instance, flush, and then save the bitmap.
  gfx.DrawString(...)//with your position information
  gfx.DrawImage(...)//with your position,font,text info
  gfx.Flush();
}
bmp.Save(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer for the question below that contains code for generating thumbnails on the fly:

[Alternatives to System.Drawing for use with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528525/alternatives-to-system-drawing-for-use-with-asp-net/1528908#1528908)