# Is it possible to calculate the width of an Excel column using .Net or OpenXml framework without using System.Drawing objects Graphics and Bitmap?

Tags: excel, openxml, pixel

I'm developing a class, which allows users to create Excel spreadsheets on the fly (using OpenXML api) and I need to calculate columns width, so that they auto-fit the widest cell in the column.

I have the following code to calculate each column's width (using the formula from [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/14/p/2306/7858.aspx) and this [tutorial](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/01/18/calculating-column-widths-in-excel-open-xml)):

```
private double CalculateColumnWidth(int textLength)
        {
            var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 11);

            float digitMaximumWidth = 0;
            using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(200, 200)))
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                {
                    var digitWidth = graphics.MeasureString(i.ToString(), font).Width;
                    if (digitWidth > digitMaximumWidth)
                        digitMaximumWidth = digitWidth;
                }
            }

            return Math.Truncate((textLength * digitMaximumWidth + 5.0) / digitMaximumWidth * 256.0) / 256.0;
        }
```

This works fine, the only question is:
Is there any way to get rid of the Bitmap and Graphics objects, that I don't really need to calculate the Excel's column width? Why is the Graphics object necessary to do this?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Column width measured as the number of characters of the maximum digit width of the numbers 0, 1, 2, …, 9 as rendered in the normal style's font. There are 4 pixels of margin padding (two on each side), plus 1 pixel padding for the gridlines. 
>   Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column.aspx

You need to calculate the width of each number 0 - 10 and determine which of those has the largest width. An easy way to accomplish this in .Net is to use MeasureString in System.Drawing.Graphics one of it's constructors requires a valid Bitmap. If your main process contains a window, i.e. you are a desktop windows app, you could construct the graphic object without a bitmap using:

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
```

It is also possible to use classes in `System.Windows.Media` part of WPF see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528525/alternatives-to-system-drawing-for-use-with-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've actually an ASP.NET applicaiton

Comment: Why do you not want to use Graphics & bitmap?