# Error saving bitmap to output stream - "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm simply trying to write a bitmap to the `Response.OutputStream`. Here's what i have:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap outputImage = 
    System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(psd.GetHBitmap());            
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
Response.Flush();

// error occurs here
outputImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

outputImage.Dispose();
Response.End();
```

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

From the [System.Drawing Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) documentation on MSDN:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.

You seem to be hitting on one of the reasons why it isn't supported.

Here is a [detailed article](http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/03/23/Why-you-should-not-use-SystemDrawing-from-ASPNET-applications.aspx) explaining the ins and outs of the issues.

There are alternatives mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528525/alternatives-to-system-drawing-for-use-with-asp-net), apart from [Windows Imaging Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentioned in the warning on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the GDI errors that I have encountered from the ASP.NET environment deal with folder / file permissions problems, which may not apply here.  Does the worker process have read access to the original file?  Are you writing a temp file to a folder which the WP does not have access to?